# running app is shut down when screen powers on

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen, t-mobile

I recently updated my Samsung S3 (T-Mobile) with the OTA update to Android 4.1.  Ever since the update, after the phone screen powers down (manually or on timer), turning the screen back on closes the running app.  I don't know if this is some new default behavior with Android 4.1, or if this is a T-Mobile customization ("feature"), or a bug (with Android or T-Mobile's customization).

I can find no information on this behavior, nor any setting addressing it.  What do your phones do?  I prefer having the app running when I power the screen back on.  I especially hate it when I lose the backstack of other apps that launched the current application.

Note: I did not wipe data after upgrade, and no task killers are installed on the device.

Thanks ahead,

Comment: It's for sure no "Android 4.1 feature". I have two devices running 4.1.1, and never noticed that (it wouldn't even make sense). I'd rather say it's either a bug, or a "special configured feature" (i.e. something configured wrongly) -- though in the latter case I'm at a loss of what to check. Maybe your provider can tell you more (reporting back can't hurt).

Comment: Same here: Opening browser, turning off screen and on again would end in the browser being visible (on Android 4.1.1). I could think of two scenarios: T-Mobile's fault while tweaking the ROM or the apps fault if its just one or a couple (but not all). Also, did you wipe data / factory reset your phone when upgrading from 4.0.4?

Comment: Just my guess but could you check if you have **task killers** installed. My guess is it could be set to kill apps when screen goes off.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, stackexchange just informed my account of this activity.

No, no task killers installed.

So I did not wipe data after performing the upgrade.  Didn't expect to have to do so, and likely would not have upgraded if that were required.